# How to identify an electron desktop app instance

Tags: api, electron, uniqueidentifier

What is the common practice to track an app instance built with electron?
More specifically, when multiple users have built and run the application on their own machines, is there a way to identify which user is which when for example they are making calls from within the app to a common shared Flask API deployed on an external server?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/systeminformation) package from NPM and then just store the user's system information into your database. so, If the user is already logged in to that system add one active flag next to system info into your database. so, now you have all information about which user logged into which system.